# How to install libqt4-core and libqt4-gui on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, qt

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But the `libqt4-core` and `libqt4-gui` packages are missing.

How could I install these packages on 16.04?

Answer (score 10):

These libqt4-core and libqt4-gui packages don't exist anymore in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer. They were dummy packages with dependencies to other packages. The following procedure will modify the Vidyo package so it uses working dependencies.

1. First make sure that all required libqt4 packages not installed by default are installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install libqt4-designer libqt4-opengl libqt4-svg libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4
   ```
2. Create a script to modify the dependency defined in the package. Use the `videbcontrol` script provided [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=636724).
3. Run the script `videbcontrol VidyoDesktopInstaller-ubuntu64-TAG_VD_3_6_3_017.deb` that will open the dependencies in a vi editor
4. Replace `Depends: libxss1,libaudio2,libasound2,libqt4-gui (>= 4.8.1), libqt4-network` with `Depends: libxss1,libaudio2,libasound2,libqt4-designer,libqt4-opengl,libqt4-svg,libqtgui4,libqtwebkit4,libqt4-network`. This creates a file named `VidyoDesktopInstaller-ubuntu64-TAG_VD_3_6_3_017.modified.deb` containing the new dependency.

   If you don't know vi, once you see the package information

   1. move the cursor using the arrows down to the line starting with `Depends:`
   2. type the letter `i` to get into insert mode
   3. copy past (right click) the new line and type return
   4. type escape to leave the insert mode
   5. type `dd` to delete the old `Depends` line
   6. type `ZZ` to save and quit the change (two upper case z)
5. Install the Vidyo package by executing the command:

   ```
   sudo apt install VidyoDesktopInstaller-ubuntu64-TAG_VD_3_6_3_017.modified.deb
   ```

Enjoy

Comment: Vidyo = facepalm

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=110458 and @chmike 
These dependencies already have higher versions as I found. It is okay to change the .deb file instead. @bean1975 has a shorter method:

```
dpkg-deb -x yourfile.deb newdir 
dpkg-deb --control yourfile.deb newdir/DEBIAN
gedit newdir/DEBIAN/control
```

and change the `libqt4-gui (>= 4.8.1)` with `libqt4-designer,libqt4-opengl,libqt4-svg,libqtgui4,libqtwebkit4`

`dpkg -b newdir modified.deb`

and you can use it now!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this as it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This was suggested by terminal itself and it did some magic and what not.

Answer (score 0):

I found [these instructions from the Vidyo website](https://support.vidyocloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/226103528-VidyoDesktop-3-6-3-for-Linux-and-Ubuntu-15-04-and-higher), the easiest to follow.  They have worked consistently across a few upgrades.

Answer (score -1):

Linked on Ubuntu section of [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu):

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/libqt4-core

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/libqt4-gui

You can install a .deb (Debian binary package) using dpkg: `sudo dpkg -i libqt4-core_4.8.6...ubuntu8_amd64.deb`

Comment: Do I have to download the files and dependencies manually? Is it there any PPA to make the install easier?

Comment: I go dependency issue when install them:dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-dbus:amd64:
 libqt4-dbus:amd64 depends on libqtdbus4 (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8); however:
  Version of libqtdbus4:amd64 on system is 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2.
 libqt4-dbus:amd64 depends on qdbus (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3~ubuntu8); however:
  Version of qdbus on system is 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2.

Comment: That says your libqtdbus4 package is too new.  Do you have another package that broke after the update that depends on libqt4-[core|gui]? For xenial there is a package libtcore4 and linbqtgui4