# Facing problems installing Qt on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, qt

I am following this [link](https://github.com/zdzhaoyong/Map2DFusion/tree/master/PIL) to install Qt on my PC.

When I type `sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ libqt4-core libqt4-dev libqt4-gui qt4-doc qt4-designer`, I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
g++ is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libqt4-core : Depends: libqt4-dbus (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
           Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
libqt4-gui : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Depends: libqt4-opengl (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Depends: libqt4-svg (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
          Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1) but 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766615/how-to-install-libqt4-core-and-libqt4-gui-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts) for help but after typing this command `sudo apt install libqt4-designer libqt4-opengl libqt4-svg libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4`, I am supposed to make a script file but i can't understand properly how to do that.

This command ran successfully `sudo apt-get install libqglviewer-dev libqglviewer2` but this `sudo apt-get install libboost1.48-all-dev` didn't, i got this error:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libboost1.48-all-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libboost1.48-all-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libboost1.48-all-dev'`

The output of `apt-cache policy libqtcore4` is:

   `libqtcore4:
   Installed: 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2
   Candidate: 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2
   Version table:
   *** 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 500
        500 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4:4.8.6+git64-g5dc8b2b+dfsg-3+deb8u1 500
        500 http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages`

How can all of this be fixed?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libqtcore4` to the question. Normal Qt packages [should not have *deb8u1* suffix](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libqtcore4). From where did you get them?

Comment: @N0rbert I added the output of `apt-cache policy libqtcore4`. I got no packages from anywhere. I installed ubuntu 16.04 and started installing softwares. You want me to download `qt4-x11` packages from the [link you have provided](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libqtcore4)?

Comment: If you are running plain Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (*xenial*), then you should remove all Debian *jessie* mentions from your sources.list files. And then retry.

Comment: Added my above comment as answer. You can accept it to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

As you are running plain Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (*xenial*), then you should remove all Debian *jessie* mentions from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`  files.

You can find such files with:

```
grep -r jessie /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

then comment out problematic lines by adding `#` to the start and retry:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ libqt4-core libqt4-dev libqt4-gui qt4-doc qt4-designer
```